# Set an enum value of the class

Tags: java

I have a class namely `OrderProviderData` provided below,

```
public class OrderProviderData {

    public enum TradingInterface {CX_CLIENT, CX_SERVER, CX_ADMIN, CX_ENGINE}

    private boolean easyTrade = false;

    private OrderPreSelect order;
    private String[] event;

    public OrderPreSelect getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(OrderPreSelect order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public String[] getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String[] event) {
        this.event = event;
    }
}
```

I would like to set the values for the `OrderProviderData` instance in the 
`receiveEvent` method based on some conditions.

```
public final class OrderProvider extends BlockingDatabaseOrderWorker {

    // some code to initiate here 

    @Override
    public final Object receiveEvent() throws Exception {

        OrderProviderData data = null;

        // get + store the TradingInterface value "tradingIf" here   
        // set the value inside the "switch" condition      

        switch(tradingIf){

            data = new OrderProviderData();

            // set the TradingInterface here
            case value1:
               //set 
               break;  //optional  

            case value2:
              //set 
              break;  //optional  

            default:
               // some code 
         }
    }

    // varify whether the easyTrade is true 
    // set the boolean 
}
```

How do I write it properly? I'm open to better advise too.

Comment: 1st you have to add a field for `TradingInterface` to your `OrderProviderData` class. 2nd, after the `switch`, you can only list the cases and nothing else

Comment: It looks like you're asking us to do your work rather than blocking on a specific issue. But, to help you, shouldn't your `receiveEvent` method take something like an event as a parameter ? in which you can pass the `TradingInterface` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the enum as field to your class. You are only defining the enum itself. (getter and setter are needed as well)

   public class OrderProviderData {

   ```
   public enum TradingInterface {CX_CLIENT, CX_SERVER, CX_ADMIN, CX_ENGINE}

   private boolean easyTrade = false;

   private TradingInterface tradingInterface;

   private OrderPreSelect order;
   private String[] event;

   public OrderPreSelect getOrder() {
       return order;
   }

   public void setOrder(OrderPreSelect order) {
       this.order = order;
   }

   public String[] getEvent() {
       return event;
   }

   public void setEvent(String[] event) {
       this.event = event;
   }

   public TradingInterface getTradingInterface() {
       return tradingInterface;
   }

   public void setTradingInterface(TradingInterface tradingInterface) {
       this.tradingInterface = tradingInterface;
   }
   ```

   }

then you can `switch` over the cases (which are the values of the enum). You can't place code between `switch` and first `case`

```
@Override
public final Object receiveEvent() throws Exception {
    Server f = new Server();

    switch (f.getInf()) {
    case CX_CLIENT:
        // set
        break; // optional

    case CX_SERVER:
        // set
        break; // optional

    default:
        // some code
    }

}
```